# php json encode problem

Tags: php, json

In order to access this data via ajax, how can I give each json encoded value a constant name?

```
 $data = array();
 foreach($query->result() as $row) {

     $data[$row->id] = $row->name;

    }
```

This returns json in this format:

{**"12428"**:"Alpine 12\" Single-Voice-Coil 4-Ohm Subwoofer",}

The id (12428) is not constant and therefore, I have nothing constant to look for when trying to decode the data with ajax.

How can I change the php code to add a constant value foreach of the encoded json items?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
$data = Array();
foreach($query->result() as $row) {
    $data[] = Array("id" => $row->id, "name" => $row->name);
}
```

Then, your JSON object looks like:

```
[{"id":"12428","name","Alpine 12\" Single-Voice-Coil 4-Ohm Subwoofer"}]
```

You can now loop through that array and get the `id` and `name` of each element.

Comment: This is exactly what I was hoping to accomplish. Thank you very much.

Answer (score 1):

Who cares.

```
js> d = {"12428":"Alpine 12\" Single-Voice-Coil 4-Ohm Subwoofer"}
[object Object]
js> for (i in d)
{
  print(d[i]);
}
Alpine 12" Single-Voice-Coil 4-Ohm Subwoofer
```

Comment: Yes, hence the "js>". `print()` is specific to the REPL though.